# Don't return variables from function

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

Help with code, variables don't return! Write with jquery and have problem with dynamic variables. Can't return var flag_target and mask_target.

```
var flag_target;
var mask_target;

$('.iti_click-1').click(function() {

    $('.firstlist').show();
    var flag_target = $('#flag-1');
    var mask_target = $('.maskNom-1');
    return flag_target, mask_target;

});

$('.iti_click-2').click(function() {

    $('.secondlist').show();
    var flag_target = $('#flag-2');
    var mask_target = $('.maskNom-2');
    return flag_target, mask_target;

});
```

Comment: For click handlers, there's nothing to receive the returned values. What do you want to do? Store them in those global variables?

Comment: As an aside, JavaScript doesn't support returning multiple values; your syntax uses the comma operator to evaluate both sides and then return the last. To return multiple values, wrap them in an array.

Comment: I want to use this values after click as selectors for other part of code

Comment: we can't return multiple variables, but we return multiple variable in the format of Array or Object format only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass a return in an event handler, this value is passed to the event handler, not to wherever you want to..., this you can't do this

```
var name = $('.eleemnt').click(function() {
    return true;
});
```

What you can do is to create a variable just outside the scope of the callback function and then save the values you want into them, like so:

```
var name = '';

$('.element').click(function() {
    name = 'Saved';
});
```

If you are scared of polluting the global space (which is a good thing to have), you can consider an [Immediately Invoked Function Expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE), like so

```
(function() {
    var name = '';

    $('.element').click(function() {
        name = 30;
        console.log(name);
    });
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

So if all you need is to be able to use the global variables after the user has clicked on the thing, simply assign the values into the global variables within the click handler:

```
var flag_target = null;
var mask_target = null;

$('.iti_click-1').click(function() {
    $('.firstlist').show();
    flag_target = $('#flag-1');
    mask_target = $('.maskNom-1');
});

$('.iti_click-2').click(function() {
    $('.secondlist').show();
    flag_target = $('#flag-2');
    mask_target = $('.maskNom-2');
});
```